# Group element with similar data with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure and trying to make a report from these:

___BillableDatas

```
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_Date   |BIL_Rate | BIL_Quantity | BIL_Status |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
|      1 | 2018-03-01 |     105 |            2 | notcharged |
|      2 | 2018-03-01 |      30 |            2 | notcharged |
|      3 | 2018-03-02 |     115 |            2 |    charged |
|      4 | 2018-03-03 |     105 |            1 | notcharged |
|      5 | 2018-03-04 |     105 |            1 | notcharged |
|      6 | 2018-03-05 |     105 |            3 | notcharged |
|--------|------------|---------|--------------|------------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |     15.000 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxes

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_BILId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|         1 |         8 |
|         1 |         9 |
|         2 |         9 |
|         3 |         9 |
|         4 |         9 |
|         5 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_BILId is the item ID link with ___BillableDatas.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

**Please note, that for `2018-03-05`, no tax is linked.**

---

So mething like this:

```
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| BIL_Date   | STX_TaxeName | BIL_Rate   | STX_Amount | STX_Total |
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2018-03-01 |        Tax 1 |    210.00  |      5.000 |     10.50 |
| 2018-03-01 |        Tax 2 |    270.00  |     15.000 |     40.50 |
| 2018-03-03 |        Tax 2 |    105.00  |     15.000 |     15.75 |
| 2018-03-04 |        Tax 2 |    105.00  |     15.000 |     15.75 |
|------------|--------------|------------|------------|-----------|
```

*I do not want item with status : **charged***

---

Explications on the totals:

- `STX_TaxeName` is the name of the concerning tax from ___SalesTaxes.
- `BIL_Rate` is the `BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity` from ___BillableDatas.
- `STX_Amount` is the tax percentage from ___SalesTaxes.
- `STX_Total` is the calculated percentage from `BIL_Rate`. (`BIL_Rate*STX_Amount/100`).

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName, BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity AS NewRate, STX_Amount
  , BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity * STX_Amount / 100 AS Total
FROM ___BillableDatas b 
JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
JOIN ___SalesTaxes t ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
WHERE BIL_Status != 'charged' 
ORDER BY BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName
```

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41166/17

---

Problems with this actual query is, it doesn't count the item #2 and I don't know why.

```
(2, '2018-03-01', '30.00', 2, 'notcharged')
```

Thanks.

Comment: In the fiddle you have != 'canceled' in mysql difference is <> and you are doing a group by with non aggregated functions, you may need to use SUM

Comment: which mysql version you using?

Comment: @DanielE., good catch for `cancelled`. SQLFiddle updated.

Comment: @Aaryan : `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64)`.

Comment: I think the above query is correct, it may count the

(2, '2018-03-01', '30.00', 2, 'notcharged')

Comment: @Aaryan it may but it don’t actually.

Comment: how u say I didn't understand

Comment: Why is Bil_Rate for Item 2 in your expected data 270 and not 60 (2*30)?

Comment: Also it seems that item 1 should have 2 applicable taxes?

Comment: Since the `2018-03-05` has no associated tax, how can you optain this output line: `| 2018-03-05 |        Tax 2 |    315.00  |     15.000 |     47.25 |` ?

Comment: @NicolasCami, good catch. Just edit the question.

Comment: @Nick, from 270 it's because I sum the 210 and the 60 for the same day.

Comment: @Nick, yes and that's why for `2018-03-01` you have 2 lines for the two taxes. But item #2 has just one tax, that's why only the second tax has `270` as sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to use grouping and aggregate functions to get your desired result:

```
SELECT BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName, SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS NewRate, STX_Amount
  , SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity * STX_Amount / 100) AS Total
FROM ___BillableDatas b 
JOIN ___ApplicableTaxes bt ON bt.ATX_BILId = b.BIL_Id 
JOIN ___SalesTaxes t ON t.STX_Id = bt.ATX_STXId 
WHERE BIL_Status != 'charged' 
GROUP BY BIL_Date, STX_TaxeName
```

Output:

```
 BIL_Date   STX_TaxeName    NewRate     STX_Amount  Total   
2018-03-01  Tax 1           210         5           10.5
2018-03-01  Tax 2           270         15          40.5
2018-03-03  Tax 2           105         15          15.75
2018-03-04  Tax 2           105         15          15.75
```